# X axis shift while plot multiple lines

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a `DataFrame` `book` containing 3 columns: `year`, `Publisher` and `Rating`.
My purpose is to plot multiple lines by `Publisher`, with `year` on the X-axis and `Rating` on the Y-axis.

```
Year    Publisher   Rating
1978    上海人民出版社 8.50
1978    商务印书馆   8.32
1979    上海人民出版社 8.15
1979    中华书局    8.56
1979    商务印书馆   8.27
1980    上海人民出版社 7.65
1980    中华书局    8.36
1980    商务印书馆   8.32
1981    上海人民出版社 8.36
1981    中华书局    8.46
1981    商务印书馆   8.33
1982    上海人民出版社 8.10
1982    中华书局    8.33
1982    商务印书馆   8.28
1983    上海人民出版社 8.24
1983    中华书局    8.52
1983    商务印书馆   8.35
1984    上海人民出版社 7.30
1984    中华书局    8.50
1984    商务印书馆   8.38
1985    上海人民出版社 8.30
1985    中华书局    8.31
1985    商务印书馆   8.17
1986    上海人民出版社 8.00
1986    中华书局    8.67
1986    商务印书馆   8.13
1987    上海人民出版社 8.30
1987    中华书局    8.38
1987    商务印书馆   8.47
1988    上海人民出版社 8.36
1988    中华书局    8.23
1988    商务印书馆   8.53
1989    上海人民出版社 8.56
1989    中华书局    8.37
1989    商务印书馆   8.23
1990    上海人民出版社 8.15
1990    中华书局    8.38
1990    商务印书馆   8.36
1991    上海人民出版社 8.13
1991    中华书局    7.54
1991    商务印书馆   8.36
1992    上海人民出版社 7.76
1992    中华书局    8.74
1992    商务印书馆   8.22
1993    上海人民出版社 7.48
1993    中华书局    8.26
1993    人民邮电出版社 9.00
1993    商务印书馆   7.88
1994    上海人民出版社 8.22
1994    中华书局    8.31
1994    商务印书馆   8.53
1995    上海人民出版社 7.93
1995    中华书局    8.27
1995    商务印书馆   8.10
1996    上海人民出版社 8.01
1996    中华书局    8.75
1996    商务印书馆   8.21
1997    上海人民出版社 7.77
1997    中信出版社   7.70
1997    中华书局    8.06
1997    商务印书馆   8.33
1998    上海人民出版社 8.02
1998    中华书局    8.63
1998    商务印书馆   7.97
1998    机械工业出版社 8.80
1999    上海人民出版社 8.14
1999    中华书局    8.14
1999    商务印书馆   8.17
1999    机械工业出版社 8.33
2000    上海人民出版社 8.14
2000    中信出版社   7.60
2000    中华书局    8.58
2000    人民邮电出版社 8.10
2000    商务印书馆   8.21
2000    机械工业出版社 8.47
2001    上海人民出版社 8.07
2001    中信出版社   7.25
2001    中华书局    7.84
2001    人民邮电出版社 7.20
2001    商务印书馆   8.30
2001    机械工业出版社 7.92
2002    上海人民出版社 7.99
2002    中信出版社   7.64
2002    中华书局    7.65
2002    人民邮电出版社 7.98
2002    商务印书馆   8.08
2002    机械工业出版社 8.42
2003    上海人民出版社 8.01
2003    中信出版社   7.74
2003    中华书局    8.12
2003    人民邮电出版社 8.30
2003    商务印书馆   8.13
2003    机械工业出版社 7.93
2004    上海人民出版社 7.71
2004    中信出版社   7.69
2004    中华书局    8.19
2004    人民邮电出版社 8.31
2004    商务印书馆   8.13
2004    机械工业出版社 8.28
2005    上海人民出版社 8.08
2005    中信出版社   7.66
2005    中华书局    7.79
2005    人民邮电出版社 8.36
2005    商务印书馆   8.08
2005    机械工业出版社 8.08
2006    上海人民出版社 8.07
2006    中信出版社   7.61
2006    中华书局    8.10
2006    人民邮电出版社 8.23
2006    商务印书馆   8.01
2006    机械工业出版社 8.20
2007    上海人民出版社 7.92
2007    中信出版社   7.72
2007    中华书局    8.02
2007    人民邮电出版社 8.06
2007    商务印书馆   8.00
2007    机械工业出版社 8.10
2008    上海人民出版社 8.02
2008    中信出版社   7.70
2008    中华书局    8.04
2008    人民邮电出版社 8.15
2008    商务印书馆   8.17
2008    机械工业出版社 7.98
2009    上海人民出版社 8.19
2009    中信出版社   7.62
2009    中华书局    8.18
2009    人民邮电出版社 7.99
2009    商务印书馆   8.12
2009    机械工业出版社 8.02
2010    上海人民出版社 8.23
2010    中信出版社   7.69
2010    中华书局    8.29
2010    人民邮电出版社 8.11
2010    商务印书馆   8.31
2010    机械工业出版社 7.77
2011    上海人民出版社 8.19
2011    中信出版社   7.62
2011    中华书局    8.34
2011    人民邮电出版社 8.01
2011    商务印书馆   8.19
2011    机械工业出版社 7.86
2012    上海人民出版社 8.31
2012    中信出版社   7.83
2012    中华书局    8.08
2012    人民邮电出版社 7.89
2012    商务印书馆   8.07
2012    机械工业出版社 7.86
2013    上海人民出版社 8.11
2013    中信出版社   7.83
2013    中华书局    8.05
2013    人民邮电出版社 7.91
2013    商务印书馆   8.15
2013    机械工业出版社 7.70
2014    上海人民出版社 8.12
2014    中信出版社   7.80
2014    中华书局    7.93
2014    人民邮电出版社 7.93
2014    商务印书馆   8.11
2014    机械工业出版社 7.44
2015    上海人民出版社 8.24
2015    中信出版社   8.01
2015    中华书局    8.50
2015    人民邮电出版社 8.21
2015    商务印书馆   8.10
2015    机械工业出版社 7.82
```

I tried to plot with the following code:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
for key,grp in book('Publisher'):
    ax = grp.plot(ax=ax, x='Year', y='Rating', label=key);
```

I got a result that looks like the X-axis was shifted. In `book` `DataFrame`, `Year` is between 1978 and 2015, but some publishers only have records from 1998-2015. May that be causing this issue?
[image]

Comment: Make sure you are plotting numbers, not strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
df.groupby("Publisher").plot("Year", "Rating", ax=ax)
plt.legend(df.Publisher.unique())
```

Comment: I can the the same result now. But the legend is wrong, it should be publishers in  `Publisher` column.

Comment: Try it now! It is fixed :D.

Comment: Please consider upvoting my answers and selecting my message as accepted answer